# I keep getting a 404 error when posting data, advice?

Tags: reactjs, debugging

So I'm building a spring-boot/react app and whilst getting data works fine posting it is another matter entirely. I keep getting an error saying 404 for Axios request. I can't find a similar problem and with network errors it isn't my fortey. Unfortunatly all i get is this network error which i know does not say a lot.

my error
`AxiosError {message: 'Request failed with status code 400', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …} code :  "ERR_BAD_REQUEST" config :  {transitional: {…}, adapter: Array(2), transformRequest: Array(1), transformResponse: Array(1), timeout: 0, …} message :  "Request failed with status code 400" name :  "AxiosError" request :  XMLHttpRequest {onreadystatechange: null, readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, …} response :  {data: {…}, status: 400, statusText: '', headers: AxiosHeaders, config: {…}, …} stack :  "AxiosError: Request failed with status code 400\n    at settle (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:42446:12)\n    at XMLHttpRequest.onloadend (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:41141:66)" [[Prototype]] :  Error`

my jsx

```
import { useState,useEffect } from "react";
import axios from 'axios';

export function Dessert(props) {

    let [price,setPrice]=useState(0);
    let [name,setName]=useState("");
    let [description,setDescription]=useState("");
    let [isEdit,setIsEdit]=useState(props.edit);

    let defaultDate=async()=>{

        if(props.id){
           let dessert;

            let path='http://localhost:8080/dessert/'+props.id;
            await axios.get(path)
                 .then(res => {
                   dessert=res.data;
               }).catch(
               function (error) {
               
              });
console.log(dessert);
            setPrice(dessert.price);
            setName(dessert.name);
            setDescription(dessert.description);
            
        }
    }

    let edit=()=>{
        setIsEdit(!isEdit);
    }
    useEffect(()=>{defaultDate();},[])
    
    let handleSubmit=async(e)=>{
       

        e.preventDefault();
        
             axios({
                method: 'post',
                url: 'http://localhost:8080/dessert',
                data: {
                    name:name,
                    description:description,
                    price:price
                }
              }); 
             
    }
    if(isEdit){
        return(
            <div>
                <form onSubmit={(e)=>handleSubmit(e)}>
                    <div>
                        <label htmlFor="name">Name:</label>
                        <input type="text" onChange={(e)=>{setName(e.currentTarget.value)}} id="name" value={name}/>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label htmlFor="desc">Description:</label>
                        <input type="text" onChange={(e)=>{setDescription(e.currentTarget.value)}} id="desc" value={description} />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label htmlFor="price">Price:</label>
                        <input type="number" onChange={(e)=>{setPrice(e.currentTarget.value)}} id="price" value={price} />
                    </div>
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
                </form>
                <button onClick={edit}>Read</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
    else if(isEdit&&props.customer){
        <div>
            <div>Name:{name}</div>
            <div>Description:{description}</div>
            <div>Price:{price}</div>
        </div>
    }
    else{
        return(
            <div>
                <div>Name:{name}</div>
                <div>Description:{description}</div>
                <div>Price:{price}</div>
                <button onClick={edit}>Edit</button>
            </div>
        );
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you getting this error for both get and post apis ?

Comment: no I do not get an error for get requests.

Comment: since you are connected to your local backend, try checking the logs in the backend. it may have something to do with it

Comment: Try adding headers like this :=>` { 
  method: 'post',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(data)
} `